# Python Delete everything except one file type

Tags: python

I have a script written to delete a specific type of extension but I would like to do the opposite of that, and delete all files **but** the extension I specify.

To delete all file types specified I have:

```
import os
import sys

directory = os.path.realpath("C:/path/to/files/")
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
     for filename in files:
          if filename.find('.pdf') > 0:
          subdirectoryPath = os.path.relpath(subdir, directory) 
          file1 = os.path.join(directory,subdirectoryPath)
          filePath = os.path.join(file1, filename)  
          os.remove(filePath)
```

How do I keep all the .pdf files?

Comment: wouldn't just say `if filename.find('.pdf') == -1:`

Comment: Or `if not filename.lower().endswith('.pdf'):`

Comment: Yes...Either of those would work. I neglected to look for the simplest solution. Thanks.

Comment: Is there anyway to get a wildcard in from of the PDF? For example find a filename with that extension? `*_WC.pdf`

Comment: For your specific example you could just substitute `.find('.pdf')` for `.find('_WC.pdf')`, but if it starts getting more complicated than that, you'll probably want to start looking into regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `glob` and `endswith`

```
    import glob
    import os
    
    path_all = glob.glob ( "C:/path/to/files/")
    
    extension=('pdf') # ('edf','json','Dat','Plb','docx','txt') _if to keep more than one extension type
    path_remove=[filename for filename in path_all if not filename.endswith ( extension )]
[os.remove ( filePath ) for filePath in path_remove]
```